# Get all categories of custom post even not assigned

Tags: plugins, functions

I know how to get all categories with `get_categories` and name custom taxonomy name, but wordpress only shows those categories those are assigned to a post. Those which are created, but not assigned, will not show up with any of these methods.

So is there any function that shows all categories that created + assigned and not assigned.

I am working in a admin panel to show all categories in a drop down list in a custom post type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know how to get all categories with `get_categories`

I think you've missed some of the arguments in [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). By default, empty categories (categories without posts) are hidden

```
'hide_empty'               => 1,
```

To get categories without posts, simply set `hide_empty` to `0`

```
'hide_empty'               => 0,
```

Here is an example

```
$categories = get_categories( 'hide_empty=0' );
```

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks. I overlooked it silly of me.

Comment: No problem, just glad it fixed your problem :-)